# Windows error 2 Python not finding my file

Tags: python, windows

I know this is going to be a simple fix but I have been trying to find the solution for way too long. Basically just trying to start off in python and I would like to open a file. I made a file called `hello.txt` and I cant seem to get Python to find it. Here's some of the most basic examples of my attempts I've tried moving the file and different capital letters and `os.stat`

```
>>> print os.path.isfile("users/nikic/documents/hello.txt")
False
>>> print os.path.isfile("c:\users\nikic\documents\hello.txt")
False
>>> print os.getcwd()
C:\Users\nikic
```

I've done just about all the suggestions I have seen through googling so now I am thinking it's just something I am missing regarding basic python setup. I am on Python2 on Windows. I have tried using the jupyternotebook and qtconsole, side question what is the recommended way to code with python for the long run? The notebook qtconsole or the microsoft vscode.

Comment: The folder is Users, not users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to paste the URL un your Windows explorer and check if the file is there.

Furthermore, you must scape backslashes. The URL should be specified as follows:

C:\\users\\nikic\\documents\\hello.txt

Comment: Copying the url didnt work but changing the backslashes did thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the Python shell as Administrator? I would recommend just coping the file path using file explorer that way there are no question you entered the file path wrong.